# Query from QSYS2.SysTables returns error "Token; void"

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am trying to read data from AS400 DB using Excel, VBA and ODBC driver. Connection is successful but none of the queries are retrieving data from DB. For ex: The select query is not working:

```
select * from QSYS2.SysTables;
```

The Client gets the following error message:

> [IBM] [System i Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5/OS] SQL0104 - Token; void. Valid tokens: <END Instruction>.

What is wrong with my query?

**Edit:** I am trying to read data from AS400 only not from DB2. I want to read the table names from SysTables(system table).

Comment: Are you talking about a DB2 database or an "AS400 Database"? Please post your actual query, plus the schema of the tables you're trying to query. Some sample data would be helpful as well. Remember: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @BryanH The AS/400 (now called IBM i on Power Systems) has DB2 integrated into the OS. The As/400 database *is* DB2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the statement termination character (`;`) for a single statement execution.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for the reply. I don't have direct access to the DB. I removed ';' and sent the app to client. will let you know the status asap.

Comment: Hi James, just got the Feedback from client. Its working fine after removing the ';'. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: James, Can i use standard SQL for AS400? or are there any differences in the syntax. When i was running a query with [] around the field name of a table, its not pulling any data. The same query works if there are no square brackets around the field name. Please clarify.

Comment: @Sri The database is a version of DB/2.  Using brackets around field names is a TSQL (MSSQL) convention.  ANSI SQL uses single quotes.  When in doubt check the documentation: [V7R1 SQL Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzintro.htm)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the Quick response.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example for retrieving queries:

```
"Select * from Tablename";
```

If it doesn't work, try checking the manual for query in Microsoft. It's different from standard SQL queries.

Comment: Microsoft??  This is IBM DB2 for i.